# Method to determine the number of questions in an exam

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a program to perform tests, however I have to fulfil a requirement: that the teacher can determine the amount of questions that each test will have. Currently each exam consists of 10 questions but I have no idea what to do or what method to modify to meet this requirement. Any ideas?

Here are my methods for the creation of exams:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #txt_question {
      height: 184px;
      width: 472px;
    }
    
    .answerBox {
      width: 400px;
    }
    
    #btn_next0 {
      margin-left: 11px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="height: 500px">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      Título del Examen:
      <asp:TextBox ID="txt_title" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox><br />
      <textarea id="txt_question"></textarea> <br />
      <div id="here_radios">
        <input id="rb_answer0" type="radio" name="answerBtn" value="0" class="answerBtn" /> <input id="txt_answer0" type="text" class="answerBox" /> <br />
        <input id="rb_answer1" type="radio" name="answerBtn" value="1" class="answerBtn" /> <input id="txt_answer1" type="text" class="answerBox" /> <br />
        <input id="rb_answer2" type="radio" name="answerBtn" value="2" class="answerBtn" /> <input id="txt_answer2" type="text" class="answerBox" /> <br />
      </div>
      <input id="btn_back" type="button" value="Pregunta Anterior" onclick="goBack()" />
      <input id="btn_next" type="button" value="Siguiente Pregunta" onclick="saveJson()" /><input id="btn_cant" type="button" value="Cantidad preguntas" onclick="saveJson()" /><br />
      <asp:Button ID="btn_finish" runat="server" Text="Terminar" OnClientClick="cstest()" OnClick="btn_finish_Click" />
    </div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_hook" runat="server" />
  </form>

  <%-- CLIENT CODE --%>

    <script>
      var exam = [];
      var index = 0;

      function saveJson() {
        var data = {}
        var gotAnswers = [];
        var radios = here_radios.getElementsByClassName("answerBtn");
        var boxes = here_radios.getElementsByClassName("answerBox");

        data["pregunta"] = txt_question.value;
        data["correcta"] = "0";
        for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
          gotAnswers.push(boxes[i].value);
          if (radios[i].checked) {
            data["correcta"] = radios[i].value;
          }
          boxes[i].value = "";
        }
        data["respuestas"] = gotAnswers;
        txt_question.value = "";

        exam[index] = data;
        index++;

        if (typeof exam[index] !== 'undefined') {
          populate(index);
        }
      }

      function goBack() {
        if (index > 0) {
          index--;
          populate(index);
        }
      }

      function populate(index) {
        var radios = here_radios.getElementsByClassName("answerBtn");
        var boxes = here_radios.getElementsByClassName("answerBox");

        txt_question.value = exam[index].pregunta;
        for (var i = 0; i < exam[index].respuestas.length; i++) {
          boxes[i].value = exam[index].respuestas[i];
          radios[i].checked = (exam[index].correcta == i);
        }
      }

      function cstest() {
        saveJson();
        var data = [];
        exam.forEach(function(e) {
          data.push(JSON.stringify(e));
        });
        hf_hook.value = data.join("▄");

      }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank u so much for your help or ideas!

Comment: I don't know C# but this *really* looks like Javascript?

Comment: If your question relates in some way to C#, please indicate clearly how it does. In the meantime I've removed your C# tag since it doesn't make any sense for your question.

Comment: 10 * exam.length seems right, but maybe too obvious?  What's the core problem?

Comment: My problem is that by default the teacher can create 10 questions, however I need that in some way that is defined by the same teacher, if he wants a test to be 5 questions, 7, 9, etc.so do it

Comment: How do you currently determine how many questions you have?

Comment: Please show your html, makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Done, so sorry I am a little bit new in SO.

Comment: Where do you want to compute the number of questions?